# How do you test one python function in a multifunction python file from the command line?

Tags: python

I have a python file something.py that has a lot of functions inside of it. I want to test one function at a time passing in variables and testing the output. How do I do I test one function from the command line with a variable to see the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launch the interpreter and import the module.

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from something import yourfunc
>>> yourfunc(a,b,c,d)
```

You won't see this exact text, but something similar: YMMV.

---

Full example:

This is something.py:

```
def funcA(): return 'A'
def twice(n): return 2 * n
def swap(a, b): return b, a
```

Now you are in your shell in the same directory as something.py (in my case `~/stackoverflow`):

```
~/stackoverflow$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from something import twice, swap
>>> twice(24)
48
>>> swap(1,2)
(2, 1)
>>>
```

If you have various python installations, call the one you need, e.g. `python2.7`, `python3.3`, `python3.4`. Or a link to one of them, e.g. on my box `(/usr/bin/)python` links to `python2.7` and `(/usr/bin/)python3` links to `python3.3`.

Comment: This is the Python interpreter.  I think the OP wants to use the commandline/terminal.  You should at least tell him how to launch the interpreter.

Comment: @iCodez Something like this?

Comment: Yea.  I know it seems redundant, but if you are inexperienced with Python, you may not know about the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to setup something special in your module to be able to call functions contained in it from the command prompt.  Something like:

```
def a(*args, **kwargs):
    print("fn a, called with: {}".format(str(args)))

def b(*args, **kwargs):
    print("fn b, called with: {}".format(str(args)))

def call_fn(args):
    fn, args = args[0], args[1:]
    if len(args) == 1:
        args = args[0]

    fn = eval(fn)
    fn(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys    
    call_fn(sys.argv[1:])
```

Now:

```
c:\temp>python my_module.py a arg1, arg2, kwarg1=something
```

results in:

```
fn a, called with: (['arg1,', 'arg2,', 'kwarg1=something'],)
```